# GraphQL Expected type to be a GraphQLInputType, but it wasn't!

Tags: java, graphql

Я использую GraphQL в веб-сервисе на `Spring Boot` и мне надо написать мутацию для обновления объектов `Invoice`. В схеме эти типы определены следующим образом:

`invoice.graphqls`:

```
type Invoice {
    uid: UUID
    number: String
    date: LocalDate
    arrivalDate: LocalDate
    senderDigest: String
    receiverDigest: String
    payerDigest: String
    departureKLADR: String
    arrivalKLADR: String
    departureCityUID: UUID
    arrivalCityUID: UUID
    departureCityName: String
    arrivalCityName: String
    freightInKops: Long
    serviceKind: String
    cargoKind: String
    amount: Int
    netVolume: Float
    netWeight: Float
    declaredValueInKops: Long
    createdDateTime: LocalDateTime
    updatedDateTime: LocalDateTime
    transportCompanyMSP: String
    transportCompanyName: String
    insuranceCompanyName: String
    senderItn: String
    receiverItn: String
    payerItn: String
    distinctInsurancePolicy: Boolean
    insurancePolicyRow: [InsurancePolicyRow]
}

input InvoiceInput {
    uid: UUID
    number: String
    date: LocalDate
    arrivalDate: LocalDate
    senderDigest: String
    receiverDigest: String
    payerDigest: String
    departureKLADR: String
    arrivalKLADR: String
    departureCityUID: UUID
    arrivalCityUID: UUID
    departureCityName: String
    arrivalCityName: String
    freightInKops: Long
    serviceKind: String
    cargoKind: String
    amount: Int
    netVolume: Float
    netWeight: Float
    declaredValueInKops: Long
    createdDateTime: LocalDateTime
    updatedDateTime: LocalDateTime
    transportCompanyMSP: String
    transportCompanyName: String
    insuranceCompanyName: String
    senderItn: String
    receiverItn: String
    payerItn: String
    distinctInsurancePolicy: Boolean
    insurancePolicyRow: [InsurancePolicyRowInput]
}
```

Здесь определены типы `Invoice`, которые могут ссылаться на объекты типа`InsurancePolicyRow`. Типы `InsurancePolicyRow` определены так:

`insurance-policy-row.graphqls`:

```
type InsurancePolicyRow {
    invoiceUID: UUID
    insuranceType: String
    insurancePolicyNumber: String
    insurancePolicyUID: UUID
    cargoKind: String
    invoiceDate: LocalDate
    arrivalPlannedDate: LocalDate
    departureKLADR: String
    departureCityName: String
    arrivalKLADR: String
    arrivalCityName: String
    totalSumInKops: Long
    declaredValueInKops: Long
    insuranceSum: Long
    freight: Long
    invoiceNumber: String
    extraVehicle: String
    forwardingAgent: String
    driver: String
    vehicleInfo: String
    insuranceSection: Int
}

input InsurancePolicyRowInput {
    invoiceUID: UUID
    insuranceType: String
    insurancePolicyNumber: String
    insurancePolicyUID: UUID
    cargoKind: String
    #invoiceDate: LocalDate
    #arrivalPlannedDate: LocalDate
    departureKLADR: String
    departureCityName: String
    arrivalKLADR: String
    arrivalCityName: String
    totalSumInKops: Long
    declaredValueInKops: Long
    insuranceSum: Long
    freight: Long
    invoiceNumber: String
    extraVehicle: String
    forwardingAgent: String
    driver: String
    vehicleInfo: String
    insuranceSection: Int
}
```

При выполнении мутаций из-за поля `insurancePolicyRow: [InsurancePolicyRow]` возникает исключение:

```
Caused by: com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaError: Expected type 'InsurancePolicyRowInput' to be a GraphQLInputType, but it wasn't!
```

Мутация описана так:

```
updateInvoice(invoice: InvoiceInput!): String
```

То есть для изменения данных используется мутация, принмающая input-тип `InvoiceInput`, в котором содержится ссылка на input-тип `InsurancePloicyRowInput`, но при этом парсер схемы почему-то считает, что поле `insurancePolicyRow` не имеет input-тип. Как исправить эту проблему?

Если убрать все поля из типа `InsurancePolicyRowInput`, ошибка все равно сохраняется.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно нужно добавить `@Service` в `MutationResolver`.
К примеру:

```
 @Service
 public class UpdateResolver implements GraphQLMutationResolver {
   String updateInvoice(InvoiceInput invoice) {
      return "dosomething";
   }
 }
```